# I am unable to create a django website in PyCharm. I am getting a syntax error, tough I am following the steps from the tutorial

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am very new to the whole python ecosystem and I am trying in learning on my own.

I am using PyCharm and I want to get familiar with django framework. I installed django, and as shown in the image, and if I call the get_version() method it gives me the version 2.1

That's what I was told [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/install/).

The next step, as they say [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/), is to create a project with the command:
$ django-admin startproject mysite

And here I am getting a syntax error. Django is installed, I am using python 3.7 which should be fine, but I don't get the problem.

It may be some tiny detail that I am missing. Any help will be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: `django-admin` is a command that is available on the bare command-line. It does not work in  the interactive interpreter.

Comment: that command has to do it in your CMD, every time you see a `$` it refers to the terminal or CMD.

Comment: Open your terminal and run those commands.

Comment: schwobaseggl, eyllanesc and Jerin Peter George. Thanks for your comments! They were useful. Next time you can answer, so I could vote up and rise your reputation a bit :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Open your terminal
2. Get in a directory you need
3. Run the command `python django-admin startproject website`
4. Get in that new directory
5. You have done it

---

Also, you should consider using virtual environment

And this [link](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWEHue8kksIaktO8KTTN_zg) is for you if you ever need something that is about Django